# GCC can access private members of outer class from friend function, MSVC cannot?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, language-lawyer

This [builds](https://godbolt.org/z/cfrzfdWaT) in GCC, but not MSVC. It seems that GCC can access private members of outer class from a friend function in a nested class, but MSVC cannot. Why is this?

```
template <typename T>
class Outer
{
public:
  struct Inner {
    friend bool operator==(const Inner& a, const Inner& b) {
      return a.outer_.private_member_ == b.outer_.private_member_;
    }
    // Both compilers are happy this if uncommented
//    bool operator==(const Inner& other) {
//      return outer_.private_member_ == other.outer_.private_member_;
//    }
   private:
    Outer<T>& outer_;
  };
  friend struct Iterator;

  private:
  int private_member_;
};

bool test(Outer<int>::Inner A, Outer<int>::Inner B)
{
    return A == B;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cfrzfdWaT)

Comment: Can you give the working example (provided as a link) ? For me, it doesn't work with gcc either.

Comment: You should define the equality operator in `Outer` (since you actually compares `Outer::private_member_`) and then use it in the equality operator of `Inner`. No friends needed. But anyway, I'm not sure of that but for me, `Inner` should not be able to see what's in `Outer` (not even what `Outer` is, it's beyond it's scope).

Comment: Probably a bug in one of the compilers.

Comment: Bug in gcc; "a friend function (11.9.3) defined within a nested class [...] has no special access rights to members of an enclosing class." [class.nest]

Comment: @molbdnilo Clang also gets  it wrong. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cfrzfdWaT). Only msvc gets it right.

Comment: Minor point: in Java there are inner and outer classes, with a somewhat mystical relationship. In C++ nested classes have no special relationship to the class they are nested in. Calling them “inner” and “outer” can be confusing because of the special meaning of those terms in Java.

Comment: @PeteBecker I’m not sure this is correct; nested classes can access the private members of the enclosing class.

Comment: @OliverHawker — nested classes are members of the class; as such, they have access to private members, just like member functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is **ill-formed** as per [class.nest#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.nest#4) which states:

> Like a member function, a friend function ([class.friend]) defined within a nested class is in the lexical scope of that class; it obeys the same rules for name binding as a static member function of that class ([class.static]), but **it has no special access rights to members of an enclosing class.**

(emphasis mine)

This means that the overloaded `operator==` in your example is not allowed to access the private data member named `private_member_` of the enclosing class `Outer<T>`.

---

To make this well-formed you can make `operator==(const Inner&, const Inner&)` a friend of `Outer<T>`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o1fcPEY3n)

Here is the gcc bug:

[GCC accepts private member access of enclosing class through friend function of inner class](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=110037)

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I assumed MSVC was at fault. Interesting that GCC and clang both have this issue.

Comment: @OliverHawker Yes it's rare that gcc and clang both get it wrong while msvc got it right.